# make an auto zoom on page depend on the browser width/height like firefox does ctr+-

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

how can i make an auto zoom on page depend on the browser width/height like firefox does ctr+-

i tried css3 scale, and it broke some parts on the page (some parts are fixed position)
i tried also javascript, many jQuery plugins with no luck

any idea how to make it ?

PS:i tried the browser zoom and it fit perfectly

thanks

Comment: Why do you need to make a zoom feature with `CTRL +` and `CTRL -` when it's already built in to the browser? Or is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: Well, i need it automaticly, without the user 'click'

Comment: You could try to define every measurement in .em instead of px, and obtain this effect by resizing the font's size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Add as many media queries as you need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        color: #666;
        background: #ccc;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 62.5%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
    #page{
        width: 600px;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 800px){
        body{
            -moz-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
            -o-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
        body{
            -moz-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.4);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
            -o-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
            transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <h2>Test 2</h2>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ut magna tortor, ut feugiat nunc. Aenean blandit imperdiet sem et interdum. Proin adipiscing metus ac sapien dictum sed fringilla odio tincidunt. Morbi tempus nulla ut dolor lacinia fringilla. Praesent ut lorem vel nisi hendrerit bibendum id at velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae metus sed nunc accumsan rutrum et ac magna. Vestibulum blandit nibh sed elit convallis in feugiat augue sollicitudin. Praesent orci felis, pharetra sed laoreet vehicula, tincidunt at mauris. Ut sed vehicula mi. 
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try css **ZOOM**:

```
body {
    zoom: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body{
        zoom: 40%;
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom